# How to create podspec file for a React Native Library

Tags: react-native, podspec, podfile

I am writing my components in React Native using `react-native` cli and am damn frustrated and confused about configuring it to be consumed as a library. Here's how the react native folder structure looks like:

```
src
    ios
        build
        projectName.xcodeproj
        projectName.xcodeworkspace
        PodFile
        PodFile.lock
        ...
    android
    index.js
    ...
```

when I open the xcode and build the project everything works fine as expected, now here's the thing. My React Native code sits into a git repository (Repo-A) which is different from an `ios-repository` (Repo-B) which contains collection of lot of independent pods.

All I want is to configure my project (Repo-A) `MyApp` to be consumed by Repo-B. I want to understand two syntax:

1. How do I add podSpec file in my Repo-A so that it points to `ios` directory so that it could be picked up by other repositories (in this case Repo-B).
2. In order to include the podfile in a specific repo (Repo-B in this case), all I need to do is the below snippet or something else? [Also how does podFile get access to these private repositories?]

Here's how I would like to consume it:

```
pod 'MyApp', :git => 'https://github.com/<username>/my-app', :branch => 'main'
```

Someone please help me understanding how can I achieve this? (Connecting the podFiles).

Additionally, one more thing I would like to know is how the versioning works? Like lets say I make some updates to my codebase, if I push it all to main and rebuild the `Repo-B` would that be sufficient to update changes in app or should I be using tags and create podSpec for each changes?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer at least part of your question:

1. In Repo-A, create a podspec file with the same name as your library: my-library-name.podspec. Add this code:

```
require "json"

package = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, "package.json")))
folly_version = '2021.06.28.00-v2'
folly_compiler_flags = '-DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG -DFOLLY_MOBILE=1 -DFOLLY_USE_LIBCPP=1 -Wno-comma -Wno-shorten-64-to-32'

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "my-library-name"
  s.version      = package["version"]
  s.summary      = package["description"]
  s.homepage     = package["homepage"]
  s.license      = package["license"]
  s.authors      = package["author"]

  s.platforms    = { :ios => "10.0" }
  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/<username>/my-app", :tag => "#{s.version}" }

  s.source_files = ['ios/']
  s.dependency "React-Core"

  # Don't install the dependencies when we run `pod install` in the old architecture.
  if ENV['RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED'] == '1' then
    s.compiler_flags = folly_compiler_flags + " -DRCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1"
    s.pod_target_xcconfig    = {
        "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "\"$(PODS_ROOT)/boost\"",
        "CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD" => "c++17"
    }

    s.dependency "React-Codegen"
    s.dependency "RCT-Folly", folly_version
    s.dependency "RCTRequired"
    s.dependency "RCTTypeSafety"
    s.dependency "ReactCommon/turbomodule/core"
  end
end
```

The s.source_files points to the ios directory so that it can be referenced by other repositories.

Documentation on sourcing other repos in podspec: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).